# How to use a custom function in a Gremlin filter?

Tags: filter, user-defined-functions, gremlin

In Gremlin I can define a function as follows:

```
def name_is_potato (v) { return v.has('name','potato').count() == 1}
```

When I call

```
name_is_potato(g.V[0])
```

I get

```
==>true
```

But when I enter

```
g.V[0].filter{name_is_potato(it)}
```

I get

```
==>java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

What's wrong with this? How can I make it run? 
I use the doghouse web based interface of Rexster.

I came across this problem when I wanted to write a function which returns true if there is any vertex named potato anywhere down the line from the given vertex.
Although I am interested in any other solutions to this problem, my goal at this stage (as a beginner Gremliner) is the evaluation/learning of Gremlin, get a feeling about how it works, experimenting with different solutions, rather than find the best one.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience but you seem to have come across a bug.  It exists in Dog House and it also fails in Rexster Console.  Interestingly, it works in the standalone Gremlin distribution.  The failure occurs at the time when the results are returned from the script engine, and are being converted to string lines for return to the console but i don't immediately see the reason why. the exception is especially not helpful.  i've created an issue in rexster to track: https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/issues/263

Comment: It also works through the RESTful interface of the same Rexster instance, indicating the same location of error as you wrote

Comment: I updated the issue in github.  There is a workaround, but not yet a solution.

Comment: New update on this issue.  The problem has been isolated back to Gremlin ScriptEngine itself (not really something that can be fixed from Rexster).  Please follow the issue here: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/issues/331

Answer (score 0):

A fix has been committed to Gremlin for this issue as part of 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT:

https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/issues/331

Building rexster from source should present the solution to the problem.  Here's the test I did in Rexster Console:

```
rexster[groovy]> def isVadas(v){v.name=="vadas"}
==>null
rexster[groovy]> g = rexster.getGraph("tinkergraph")
==>mocktinkertransactionalgraph[vertices:6 edges:6 directory:data/graph-example-1]
rexster[groovy]> isVadas(g.v(2))
==>true
rexster[groovy]> isVadas(g.v(1))
==>false
rexster[groovy]> g.V.filter{isVadas(it)}
==>v[2]
```